# Java JPanel moves slightly on its own + extra

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a problem. Now I'm working with 3 panels, mainPanel and 2 others ( btnPanel and iconPanel).
So the problem is when I push button "reset" I delete iconPanel and add it again it moves slightly to right on its own. Maybe someone can check my code where the problem?

Also I dont want to create another question so I give 2 extra questions.

Do I delete JPanel properly? 
If I delete JPanel with components inside they also will be removed from memory?

P.s. Im beginner so dont judge me :)

```
Main.java

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Made by Mac4s");
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setSize(310, 654);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setResizable(false);          




                MainScreen screenObj = new MainScreen();  
                screenObj.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(310, 650));
                frame.add(screenObj);
            }
        });
    }
}

MainScreen.java

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;



public class MainScreen extends JPanel {
    private JButton resetBtn;
    private JPanel btnPanel;
    private JPanel iconPanel;

    public MainScreen() {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());  
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        setBtnPanelAndComp();
        setIconPanelAndComp();

        add(mainPanel);
    }

    private void setBtnPanelAndComp() {
        btnPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        btnPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        btnPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(295, 30));

        setButtons();

        this.add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    private void setButtons() {
        resetBtn = new JButton("Reset");
        resetBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                resetIconLabel();

            }               
        });

        btnPanel.add(resetBtn, BorderLayout.WEST);
    }

    private void resetIconLabel() {
        this.remove(iconPanel);
        this.repaint();
        this.revalidate();
        setIconPanelAndComp();

    }

    private void setIconPanelAndComp() {
        iconPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        iconPanel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        iconPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(295, 580)); 

        this.add(iconPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
}
```

Comment: you should `setVisible()` _after_ adding all the components

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "the problem is when I push button "reset" I delete iconPanel and add it again it moves slightly to right on its own."

The reason this happens is because a `JPanel` has a `FlowLayout` by default. You're trying add to a `BorderLayout` position that is non-existent.

```
this.add(iconPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

The `FlowLayout` has default gaps on the edges, so when you set the size of the frame, those gaps aren't respected. To over come this, it is also preferable to `pack()` the frame, instead of `setSize()`

The reason `BorderLayout` works (doesn't shift) is because preferred sizes aren't respected.

If you set the layout in the constructor to `this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());` You won't have the shift.

```
public MainScreen() {
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());                  <----
    setBtnPanelAndComp();
    setIconPanelAndComp();
    add(mainPanel);
}
```

**Notes**

- You should `setVisible()` *after* adding components. That's why your frame jumps when you first open it. You are setting the frame visible, *then* moving it around with the location, and adding components.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I dont want to be greedy, but can you help with that extra questions. Of course if you have time. :)

Comment: In short, yes you are doing it correctly and it _does_ free up space.